# Rails: Infinite Scroll, load spinner instead of text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, assets

All works properly, but I want to show a spinner loading instead of text. This is my code in Page.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
 if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll().
```

This line show the text:

```
 $('.pagination').text("Fetching more...")
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps css @keyframes suits just fine for your case, you can check possible implementation here https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

for example you can take

```
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.loader {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-indent: -99999em;
  margin: 55px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.loader:before {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dc5c1;
  border-radius: 10.2em 0 0 10.2em;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: -0.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
  animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
}
.loader:after {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #0dc5c1;
  border-radius: 0 10.2em 10.2em 0;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: 5.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
  animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

and then in your coffescript just add and remove the class "loader" loading div, or add/remove div with such a class.

```
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```